# how to run my unit test target automatically

Tags: ios, xcode, git, unit-testing

i have build a new target on `XCODE` for my `IOS` app that contains code for `UNIT TESTING`, it works great when i am running the test when i am selecting the scheme and run a `TEST`. now i want this test to happen every time a build is happen. and every time i am pulling new code from git.

up until now iv'e understand that this is actually possible when working with a `GIT` and want to have control every time a new code is checked in.

anyone have some knowledge ?